# iText setMinimumHeight on splitted cell

Tags: height, itext, cell

I call setMinimumHeight on a cell with some text that is split over two pages. In the second page there are only 2 lines of text but the height of the cell is set to "minimum height".

I'm not sure if this is the desired behavior... and if then, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Anybody found a solution?